# prevent some commands from executing with superuser privileges

Tags: bash, sudo

I'm new to bash. I have written a script consisting of many lines and commands. This is a setup file for getting and installing several packages. As a result I need to use many install commands in my script like this command:

```
sudo apt install python2.7 python-pip
```

As an attempt to avoid using so many `sudo` in my script, I decided to remove `sudo` before each command and execute the script like `sudo ./setup.sh`.

It works fine, but the problem is that there are some commands that doesn't really need `sudo` before them, like `mkdir`, `wget` and ...

When I run my script using `sudo ./setup.sh`, the directories that are created using this script can not be removed, copied or edited without using `sudo`, however I wanted them to be accessible for all users. Therefore, my question is that:

When running a script with sudo (like `sudo ./setup.sh`), is there any way not to execute some of its inside commands like `mkdir` or `wget` with superuser privileges?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I mean when I want to delete the directories and files that are generated using this script, I cannot do it. I can remove them only using `sudo rm`.

Comment: That would be the same, what ever user you used. However in that case, root would also be able to do it. It would however do nothing to enable **ALL** users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `sudo`, you start a new shell as whatever user you told `sudo` to switch to (root, by default). This will set the `SUDO_USER` variable to the username of that user:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "SUDO_USER: $SUDO_USER"
```

If I run this script as me, I get nothing since the variable isn't set:

```
$ foo.sh
SUDO_USER:
```

But if I run it with `sudo`, the variable is set:

```
$ sudo foo.sh
SUDO_USER: terdon
```

With this in mind, you can simply run the specific commands you want to be run as a regular user, using the username of the user launching the script. So, change your `wget` and `chmod` and any other commands you want to run as a regular user in the script, and make them run with `sudo -u $SUDO_USER` so they will be run as a regular user instead of root:

```
apt install python2.7 python-pip ## will run as root
sudo -u $SUDO_USER mkdir foo ## will run as $SUDO_USER
```

Using the `SUDO_USER` variable ensures that any directories and files you create will be owned by the user who launched the script and you don't need to explicitly tell your script the name of that user each time you run it.

Comment: Should I use `$USER or $SUDO_USER?

Comment: @Pablo you should use `$SUDO_USER`, as I say in the answer. When you run `sudo command`, the value of `$USER` will be root, so there's no point in using `$USER`.

Answer (score 1):

To make the directories created by mkdir to be used by all users , you need to change the permission to WORLD readable/writable using chmod command.

In the script, after you execute `mkdir`, use the command below:

```
chmod -R 755  «directory-name»
```

(Readable to all, writable only by root)

or

```
chmod -R 777  «directory-name»
```

(Readable and also writable by all users in the system)

For `wget`, use the `chmod` command after downloading.

OR

Still if you want to execute command as another user, use su command:

```
su - «username» -c 'command to be executed'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I started this, but we shouldn't do it in the comments. I [created a room for the discussion instead.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106553/discussion-on-answer-by-stalin-vignesh-kumar-prevent-some-commands-from-executin).